# REST @FormParam values are null

Tags: java, rest, form-parameter

I have the following in html

```
<form name="myform" method="POST">
    <input type="text" id="products" name="products" />
</form>

function myForm() {
        var url = 'rest/products/details/';
        var formData = $("#myform").serializeArray();
        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        dataType: 'json',
            data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            //callfunc(data);
        }
    });
}
```

In Java server side I have the following

```
@POST
@Path("/details")
public List<Product> findProducts(@FormParam("products") String products) {
.....
.....

log.info("prod "+products); --> getting null
```

For some reason products is null even though I am passing correct values from html. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Try [`serialize()`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/), instead of [`serializeArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/). Did you do a `console.log(formData)` to see what it looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is rather silly,I was using name instead of id and that resulted in getting null in server side for all form elements. I have changed to

`<form id="myform" method="POST">` 
it works well

However 
`<form name="myform" method="POST">` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

```
function myForm() {
        var url = 'rest/products/details/';
        var formData = "products=asasa" ;
        $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        dataType: 'json',
            data: formData,
        success: function (data) {
            //callfunc(data);
        }
    });
}
```

try this and remove @consumes annotation. the problem is in the `$("#myform").serializeArray()` function from jquery.

Comment: Id I am using `var formData = "products=asasa" ;` then I am able to receive data in server.

Comment: as @peeskillet says in previous comment try with `serialize()` instead of `serializeArray()`. Here is the doc: https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: Finally I figured out the issue, it was rather silly. Instead of id I was using name in <form name="myform" method="POST"> if I use <form id="myform" method="POST"> it works well. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try `Consumes` annotation

```
@POST
@Path("/details")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public List<Product> findProducts(@FormParam("products") String products) {
.....
.....
```

Comment: I have tried this, but still I am not able to get products value. In fact it is null.